# Can somebody explain how to model seasonality in timeseries, via Fast Fourier Transform, FFT?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, fft

A series, yt, can be decomposed and modeled thus:

`yt = drift(or trend) + seasonality + noise`, which is in tandem with Parseval's theorem.

One of the techniques used to model a series's seasonality is the application of the FFT algorithm. I have read few texts about it(FFT) and I understand what it does but how do I incorporate it back into the model, before modeling for noise?

I suppose FFT transforms a signal into a linear combination of sine and cosine functions of frequencies that makes up the signal. How then do I incorporate it back into the model? I have read few examples I haven't understood properly, or should I say my curiosity isn't satisfied yet.

For example, consider the series yt:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeature
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

# estimators
linear_model = LinearRegression()
poly_feat = PolynomialFeatures(degree=3)

# modeling trend
pipe = Pipeline([ ('poly_trans', poly_feat), ('regressor', linear_model) ])
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train).score(X_test, y_test) # 0.76
```

Now suppose I am to model the seasonality in this series, where I get employ FFT, I think I would attempt to use a FeatureUnion to combine the trend and seasonal effect thus:

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft

poly_fft_union = FeatureUnion([ ('poly_trans', poly_feat), ('fft', fft) ])
```

This is where I am stuck. fft transformation returns complex numbers. I do not want to share more information because I don't want folks around to make assumptions that I know some aspects of this. Examples I have studied online either avoided using the fft or wrote a custom Estimator that applied the sin/cosine Fourier transformation formula directly.

If I weren't stuck, then I would model the trend and seasonality thus

```
pipe = Pipeline([ ('union', poly_fft_union), ('regressor', linear_model)
pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I need to feed my curiosity here. Please, anyone?!